# I'm on drush version 6 & can't do a drush status on my drupal8 site, whats the story?

Tags: drush

drush status says I'm on drush version 6  How can I get drush to work with Drupal8 ?  Do I have to grab a later version of drush directly from github?  Any directions for this?  Thanks.

This is the error message I'm getting when trying to run drush against my drupal8 install:

Drush 6.0 does not support Drupal . See http://drupal.org/project/drush for more     [error]
information.

Comment: How did you install Drush? What kind of machine are you on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a module bug report. If you find a bug, please report it to the relevant issue queue on Drupal.org (or GitHub as it happens to be in this case). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in Drush 6.0.0 that was caused when Drupal 8 changed the way that the Drupal VERSION constant was defined.  This has been fixed in the master branch on GitHub; currently, the only way to use Drush with Drupal 8 is to clone the master branch directly.  There should be a 6.1.0 release out shortly to address this.

For more information, see:

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/63

**UPDATE:**  I mis-spoke above.  Drush 6.x supported Drupal 8 until the recent release of Drush 6.0.0.  Now, only the master branch (Drush 7) supports Drupal 8. So, there is no way to get Drush 6 to work with Drupal 8; you must use the master branch.  When 6.1.0 comes out, Drush will correctly tell you that Drush 6.1.0 does not support Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks I look forward to 6.1.0 or perhaps I'll brave the bleeding edge and will check it out from git

Comment: Nope, I now get "Drush 6.1.0 does not support Drupal . See http://drupal.org/project/drush for more information."

Comment: Try again with the latest master from GitHub.  If you still have problems, open an issue on GitHub.