# Using drush on drupal 8?

Tags: drush, caching, 8

Dursh works very well with my Drupal 7, but when I try running Drush on Drupal-8 directory it throws some error message,

```
$drush pm-list

Command pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run[error]
this command.
The drush command 'pm-list' could not be executed.                                                                                 [error]
A Drupal installation directory could not be found
```

could anyone tell me the solution for this problem?

any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which version of drush? https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#drush-versions has a nice table, but in short you need the `master` branch from github if you want to work with Drupal 8.

Comment: so it was version compatibility issue, my version was 4.5, i didn't really noticed that. Thank you sir.

Comment: Drush 7 works with Drupal 8. See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85281/im-on-drush-version-6-cant-do-a-drush-status-on-my-drupal8-site-whats-the-s

Comment: Yes and `master` contains Drush 7 at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used drush with drupal 8, but these errors are sometimes experienced with D7 if you run drush from outside a site directory (eg sites/mysite.com) if the 'default' site is invalid or not defined.

Is it possible this might be the case here?