# Drush does not support Drupal?

Tags: drush

My Drush 5.x was working normally and then suddenly threw this message.

I upgraded to Drush 6 using the Windows installer but I am getting the same message.

This is a Windows 7 machined and I stress that I had been using Drush for hours and as far as I can recall, nothing unusual happened between the last successful use and the sudden error message.

I will be grateful for any tips to resolved this.

Comment: Are you in your Drupal application directory while running Drush?

Comment: To the moderators -- too many possible answers?  That is why most noobes ask.  They have lost track of a line of approach. We need experts not to give answers but to frame the question so can recover an orderly approach.  Perhaps consider this feedback to make Drupal Answers more useful to more people?

Comment: This is duplicate of: [I'm on drush version 6 & can't do a drush status on my drupal8 site, whats the story?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/85281/1908)

Answer (score 4):

What version of Drupal are you using?  Drupal 8 is only supported by the 'master' branch of Drush on github.  Older versions of Drush say "Drush does not support Drupal 8."  There was a bug in some versions of Drush where the version number of Drupal is not reported correctly.  Perhaps this is what you are encountering.

Comment: Now the question title makes sense. I was struggling with understanding which message error the OP encountered.

Comment: Is it possible that all in a sudden Drush throws that error? For what I can understand, the user was using Drush for hours, and suddenly he got that error. Did he use it with a Drupal 7 version, and then used it with Drupal 8, or is there anything else?